# rails 3.1: postgres: why does db:create ignore my database.yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake, adaptor

Here's my database.yml entry:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: hi5fit_development
  user: postgres
  password: postgres
  pool: 5
```

Here's my command-line:

rake db:create

Here's the error I get:

```
db/test.sqlite3 already exists
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Eric"
/Users/Eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails-31/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in `initialize'
/Users/Eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails-31/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in `new'
... Many lines left out
```

This has happened on two different machines, one running Postgres 8.4 on OSX 10.5,
the other Postgres 9.2 on OSX 10.6, both with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.1, so I'm most
likely making a systematic error, and not running into a one-time glitch.  Why is rake
trying to use my login name and not the database name provided in config/database.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `username`, not `user`.

Comment: Thanks, I inherited this code, don't know how they had it working before.